# How to take all the words in one normal array from the database in the Laravel framework with a minimum waste of time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to take all the words from the database into **default array**. I have more than 50,000 words in the database, and most likely this number is up to a million. Therefore, I want this operation did not take much time. I tried such ways in which not a word is put into the usual array. That is, the words are passed to the associative array:

```
$words = DB::table('words')->pluck('word');
dump($words);
```

Result:

```
Collection {#197 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    0 => "тоҷик"
    1 => "ӯзбек"
    2 => "қирғиз"
    3 => "эрон"
    4 => "япон"
    5 => "англис"
    6 => "тоҷик"
    7 => "ӯзбек"
    8 => "қирғиз"
    9 => "эрон"
    10 => "япон"
    11 => "англис"
  ]
}
```

Second method:

```
$words = DB::select("SELECT `word` FROM `words`");
dump($words);
```

Result:

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => {#210 ▼
    +"word": "тоҷик"
  }
  1 => {#207 ▼
    +"word": "ӯзбек"
  }
  2 => {#209 ▼
    +"word": "қирғиз"
  }
  3 => {#206 ▼
    +"word": "эрон"
  }
  4 => {#208 ▼
    +"word": "япон"
  }
  5 => {#205 ▼
    +"word": "англис"
  }
  6 => {#204 ▼
    +"word": "тоҷик"
  }
  7 => {#203 ▼
    +"word": "ӯзбек"
  }
  8 => {#202 ▼
    +"word": "қирғиз"
  }
  9 => {#200 ▼
    +"word": "эрон"
  }
  10 => {#213 ▼
    +"word": "япон"
  }
  11 => {#214 ▼
    +"word": "англис"
  }
]
```

And I want to take all the words in this form on the usual array:

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => "тоҷик"
  1 => "ӯзбек"
  2 => "қирғиз"
  3 => "эрон"
  4 => "япон"
  5 => "англис"
  6 => "тоҷик"
  7 => "ӯзбек"
  8 => "қирғиз"
  9 => "эрон"
  10 => "япон"
  11 => "англис"
]
```

I need this to get the difference between the two arrays. The input array is an upbeat array so I need to take all the words from the bass to add to the copious array. In general, is there any function like `array_diff()` in the Laravel framework itself?

```
$diff = array_diff($input_array, $words_from_db);
```

And add the difference to the database:

```
foreach ($diff as $value) {
    DB::table('words')->insert(['word'=>$value]);
}
```

How correct is my method of adding a large number of words (data) to the database? Can I need to optimize if of course it's possible?

In the general i found this function from Laravel:

```
public function diff($items)
{
    return new static(array_diff($this->items, $this->getArrayableItems($items)));
}
```

But how I can use it for get diff 2 arrays? Input array will be default array and second array words from db

Thank you all in advance for answering and forgive me for apologizing for grammatical errors in the question.

Comment: what laravel version?

Comment: Laravel 5.5 @OmisakinOluwatobi

Comment: @John Is the only thing you are trying to do is insert new words without duplicates into the table?

Comment: Yes, but my input words will be in default array @Aknosis

Comment: If possible I would not bother loading the existing words to diff inside of PHP. If the amount of words is as large as you say, you are going to spend on a lot time querying/diffing the data. You can accomplish the same thing entirely in MySQL

Comment: How can this be done? @Aknosis

Comment: INSERT IGNORE? @Aknosis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish inserting unique words into the database entirely inside of MySQL, this should always be faster than pulling all the words into memory, diffing them and sending in the unique values.

To do this you need to add a unique index on your words column. (ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `idx_word` ON `db`.`words` (word);
```

Then on your insert you need to add `ON DUPLICATE KEY` (Laravel query builder does not support on duplicate key - can use raw to insert) ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

```
INSERT INTO word VALUES ('foo'),('bar') ON DUPLICATE KEY word = VALUES(word);
```

I would use on duplicate key rather than insert ignore. I think insert ignore may hide other potential issues unrelated to duplicate key.

Comment: Ok, your code working good. And how I can using this query `INSERT INTO word VALUES ('foo', 'bar') ON DUPLICATE KEY word = VALUES(word);` add my word from array to database in minimum loss time?

Comment: For example how I can add words using function DB::insert() with your query?

Comment: Can you show me how to use your query in Laravel 5.5? @Aknosis

Comment: @John unfortunately I believe you would have to manually build the query and use `DB::insert([INSERT INTO word VALUES (?),(?) ON DUPLICATE KEY word = VALUES(word);], $input_words)`. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blaravel%5D+on+duplicate+key

Answer (score 0):

You can get diff two array in Laravel 5.5 so:

```
$words = DB::table('words')->pluck('word')->toArray(); // Collection converted to simple array
```

And you can use default function in php for get diff arrays:

```
$result = array_diff($input_default_array, $words);
```