# How I can correct my function - Laravel-5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I write this function for inserting words from array:

```
public function ins($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        DB::table('words')->updateOrInsert(['word' => $value]);
    }

}
```

And I created index for duplicate values in mysql using this query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `idx_word` ON `db`.`words` (word);
```

But when I use my function for add words it take this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where (`word` = ?) limit 1' at line 1 (SQL: update `words` set  where (`word` = microsoft) limit 1) ◀"
```

How to be correctly my function for adding not duplicate words to database in Laravel 5.5?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the method signature for [`updateOrInsert`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2160):

```
bool updateOrInsert(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```

If the row attributes already exist (in your case, if the word is already there), it'll update based on what gets passed into the second parameter.

To fix your problem, you can simply repeat the attributes parameter to fill the values parameter:

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($value) {
    DB::table('words')->updateOrInsert(['word' => $value], ['word' => $value]);
});
```

Comment: Isn't the signature expects `DB::table('words')->updateOrInsert(['word'],[$value]);` ?

Comment: Nah, it expects an associative array on either side

Comment: What will be the speed of your code? Whose code will work more quickly on yours? Yours or the Maraboc code? @Chris Forrence

Comment: Well of course for a large number of words more than a million

Comment: Do whatever pre-/post-processing you'd like; the first step is getting it working, then refactoring to improve performance if performance is an issue.

Comment: @Otabek You could measure the performance yourself by executing both functions in the same environment that you're using as a different environment could lead to different results.

Comment: When I add you code to loop it take error: "Undefined variable: value". But value have in loop

Comment: Because DB::transaction uses a closure, it needs to inherit variables from the parent level using `use`, as shown in the edit.

Comment: How I can get number of new inserted words? @Chris Forrence

Comment: I'd advise asking a separate question; each Stack Overflow question is really supposed to be one question, or else it gets too broad.

Comment: Ok, then I create new question if I need to it @Chris Forrence

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use Model instead of Query builder i.e. DB::table.

Word.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Word extends Model
{
    protected $table = "words";
}
```

Use **updateOrCreate** on ***Word*** Model like this.

```
Word::updateOrCreate(['word' => $value]);
```

Note: not tested, giving you an outline.

Comment: Only suggestion I'd make is that you won't need the `protected $table = "words";` line, since by default, it defines the table name to be the plural form of the word

Comment: @ChrisForrence thanks for your suggestion. I generally don't use protected $table but to be on the safer side I prefer to include it in the answer. :) Again appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Fair enough, and it doesn't do any harm at all by including it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
public function ins($array)
{
    $wordsNotExists = array();
    $wordsToInsert = array();

    $array = array_unique($array);
    $wordsThatExists = DB::table('words')
            ->whereIn('word', $array)
            ->pluck('word');

     $wordsNotExists = array_diff ($array, $wordsThatExists->toArray());

    foreach ($wordsNotExists as $key => $value) {
        $wordsToInsert[] = ['word' => $value];
    }

    DB::table('words')->insert($wordsToInsert);
}
```

---

With the index created you can insert the data with the Raw method :

```
foreach (array_unique($array) as $key => $value) {
    DB::insert('INSERT INTO words VALUES (?) ON DUPLICATE KEY word = VALUES(word)', $value);
}
```

Comment: What happens if a word was added during `foreach` loop?

Comment: I think Alex is asking if the word gets inserted into the database in a separate thread/call while the foreach-loop is going; is that correct?

Comment: What if my array with words is very large? For example, a million words. What is the degree of time optimization for this function? And what do you think about using query example `INSERT INTO word VALUES (?) ON DUPLICATE KEY word = VALUES(word);` @Maraboc

Comment: Sorry @Maraboc, you didn't get the question. Let's say you have a list of 200 words to add, and you do 200 `wherex` request to the database, which takes some time. At the time you made the first request the first word did not exist in the database, and you put it into the array. But imagine another script inserted this exactly word before you checked the last 200th one from the list. My question is about behaviour of your script in this scenario.

Comment: @AlexBlex I agree with you i edited my answer for this case adding `array_unique()` ;)

Comment: @Otabek As i said in the first statement `If there is no problem in checking the database with a query` means if the number is not large ;)

Comment: You can optimize for a large amount of data your function? @Maraboc

Comment: @Otabek What about the last version ?

Comment: If possible I would not bother loading the existing words to diff inside of PHP. If the amount of words is as large as you say, you are going to spend on a lot time querying/diffing the data. You can [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792801/how-to-take-all-the-words-in-one-normal-array-from-the-database-in-the-laravel-f)

Comment: What do you think about the question which I gave you the link for viewing?@Maraboc

Comment: @Otabek Check the update again if it will work this time ;)

Comment: How to use method Raw? Just with one line of code which you wrote you can add a whole array of words without using a loop? Or what will be the full form of the function using the Raw method? @Maraboc

Comment: After searching i think you will need to loop over the array to insert each value :p

Comment: In the new code you added, if the number of words is 1000, then the query will be executed 1000 times, and if in the array all words are new words? @Maraboc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156945/discussion-between-maraboc-and-otabek).